# Gauss Jordan elimination on electrical circuit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Gentlemen, thought my practice in solving Gauss Jordan elimination questions, I faced this question and I got stuck in it for quite long time, and I couldn't figure out the answer. Could you lend me a hand in solving this question. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome @AsaadMaher  ! Consider writing to the point questions. Also you need to write in your question which part you are getting stuck in and  show your attempt to the question.

Comment: There are women as well as men active on this site, hence the term “gentlemen” is too narrow to address all readers.

Comment: For subtask **b)** consider the following:

Let $A$ be the matrix from the subtask.

$\det(A)=-1\times\det\begin{pmatrix}4 & 8 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & 1\\
-1 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}-1\times\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 8 & -1\\
3 & 2 & 1\\
2 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+1\times\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & -1\\
3 & -1 & 1\\
2 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}-1\times\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & 8\\
3 & -1 & 2\\
2 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$

Working out the determinants of those $3\times3$ matrices should be fairly easy using the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).